# 2017 iMac (27” 5K) not working with headset microphone

Tags: macos, imac, audio, headphones, microphone

I recently purchased a 27" 5K iMac (2017 model) and am trying to use a [KOTION EACH G9000 3.5mm Game Gaming Headphone](http://www.kotioneach.com/mediacenter/kotion-each-g9000-3-5mm-game-gaming-headphone/) with it.

The headphones work fine, but I'm having problems using the microphone. The Microphone is recognised in System Preferences > Sound, but isn't working when I play Fortnite.

So far I've:

- played around with Fortnite's settings
- plugged/unplugged the headset
- purchased and tried using a 3.5mm/USB adapter
- restarted the iMac
- ensured all my software is up-to-date
- checked with Apple on whether they sell an Apple-branded headset

**Is this a hardware capability issue? If not, how might I troubleshoot this further? Am I missing something in the settings somewhere?**

My goal is to play Fortnite, enjoy music, and start recording once I sort out the microphone issue.

**[UPDATE]**

Here are two screenshots to show my current Sound preferences:

[image]

[image]

Comment: A few questions: (1) Can you add a screenshot of your System Preferences > Sound settings (otherwise we can't tell if you're missing something). (2) Have you tested the microphone with other software to see if it records? If so what were the results? If not, can you try and report back? (3) Have you tried using the Audio MIDI Setup app (by default, this app is located in Applications > Utilities > Audio MIDI Setup). Remember you can [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/336957/edit) your question to provide additional details.

Comment: Hopefully the screen shots come through clearly. When I am in ‘Input’ as I make an audible sound, the mic captures it. Didn’t know if it was the headset mic or mic built into Mac. I tap very gently on headset mic with zero ambient noise, and headset mic captures sound. So I can only presume the headset mic is working correctly within the Sound Pane in System Preferences. This method works when headset is connected via 3.5mm jack to back of Mac AND this method works when headset is connected via 3.5mm/USB adapter to back of Mac.

Comment: I have not tried recording using other software. Will make attempt soon. But before I jump into that I am working on the Audio MIDI App. I will post results